# Why Javascript code gets running while trying to save ACE editor's content

Tags: javascript, editor, markdown, ace-editor

I am trying to save a content of an [ace](http://ace.c9.io) editor which contains some JavaScript sample code as following:

```
<script>
  (function(){
     alert("I SHOULD NOT BE RUNNING");
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

but when I am trying to add the editor's content using following code:

```
function save(editor) {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    $("form[name='note'] input[name='note_title']").val($("#editor-title").val());
    $("form[name='note'] textarea[name='note_body']").html(editor.getValue());
    $("form[name='note'] input[name='version']").val("ace");
    $("form[name='note']").submit();
}
```

A message box with `I SHOULD NOT BE RUNNING` message will pop-out!!!

I have bound the ace editor to following:

```
<div id="editor" class="" style="display: none;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($body) ?></div>
```

And run ace editor with following:

```
window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
window.editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/markdown");
window.editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'save',
    bindKey: {win: 'Ctrl-S',  mac: 'Command-S'},
    exec: save
});
```

#### My questions:

1. Why the JavaScript content gets running?
2. How can I prevent it from running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops!! i found why!!!
In `function save(editor)` i should add the editor's content not using `html()` function; but with `val()`.

The correct `save()` function would be:

```
function save(editor) {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
    $("form[name='note'] input[name='note_title']").val($("#editor-title").val());
    // WRONG [ IT WILL RUN THE JS ]
    // $("form[name='note'] textarea[name='note_body']").html(editor.getValue());
    // CORRECT
    $("form[name='note'] textarea[name='note_body']").val(editor.getValue());
    $("form[name='note'] input[name='version']").val("ace");
    $("form[name='note']").submit();
}
```

I post my own question's answer, maybe help somebody later. :)